# Right debug configuration for Grails app using VSCode

Tags: debugging, grails

I have a Grails project which i can run as :

```
grails run-app
```

Now I need to create a **launch.json** file to debug the same using VSCode. I know I can put grails in "debug" mode as :

```
grails -debug run-app
```

But how can I apply this to my launch file in VS Code?

This is the default template when I select Java :

```
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```